# PDO - MySQL - Database Structure

Tags: mysql, database, pdo, structure

First of all, I'm fairly new to all PDO and MySQL coding. I'm working on a website and I'm not sure how I should build my database. I looked for an answer but I couldnt find a clear one so I'm creating this question.

Basicly the website I'm working on is a text based game. There're buttons for players to do some actions. For example clicking to "Workout" button increases players power based on gold and energy. To do that, my code checks players gold and energy. Then if both checks are passed, it increases players power.

My current database structure is like this (Tables):

```
 resources
      ID,
      Energy,
      ...

 inventory:
      ID,
      Gold,
      ...

 attributes:
      ID,
      Power,
      ...
```

I have to prepare and execute 6 different PDO statements for "Workout" button. Three times to get information that I need from tables and three times to update tables. For some other buttons, it gets up to 8 - 9.

I heard that using more than 3 or 4 prepared statements in a code really strains the code. But I also heard that creating tables with so many columns strains the database. I really dont know what to do. Can anyone lead me to right direction?

Comment: generally speaking, mysql likes you to challenge it. It can probably handle it. If you don't show it its propers, it will punish you. Like table scans. PHP will punish you, like turning PHP into the db engine

Comment: PDO has nothing to do with database structure. And big databases usually mean hundreds of tables, millions of rows, thousands of queries per second. Don't worry about performance - when you have that problem, you will also have the resources to solve it.

Comment: What the guys before me wrote is true. Whoever told you that using more than 3 or 4 prepared statements in code strains the code is an idiot, don't listen to that person again. The code exists to help *you*. If you need 4 or 40 prepared statements, then you use them.

Comment: @ddinchev Yes, I know that PDO has nothing to do with database structure but I'm worried about performance. I dont want to strain my PHP code just because of bad database structuring. :)

Comment: @N.B. Alright! Thanks a lot! :)